# Custom Stack<T> made with IEnumerable<T> and Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, stack, ienumerable

I've got this problem that I've been trying to figure out. 
I am trying to make the CustomStack act like Stack, only implementing the Push(T), Pop(), Peek(), and Clear() methods. I've got this code, and I thought it was correct, but the output displays only half of the numbers. I think it's something to do with the push method, but I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Enumerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomStack<int> collection = new CustomStack<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                collection.Push(i);
                Console.WriteLine(collection.Peek());
            }
            collection.Push(23);
            foreach (int x in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(collection.Pop());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("current", collection.Peek());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class CustomStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {

        private T[] arr;
        private int count;

        public CustomStack()
        {
            count = 0;
            arr = new T[5];
        }


        public T Pop()
        {
            int popIndex = count;
            if (count > 0)
            {
                count--;
                return arr[popIndex];
            }
            else
            {
                return arr[count];
            }

        }

        public void Push(T item)
        {

            count++;
            if (count == arr.Length)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length + 1);
            }

            arr[count] = item;


        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            count = 0;

        }

        public T Peek()
        {
            return arr[count];
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return count;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator(this);
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new MyEnumerator(this);
        }

        public class MyEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            private int position;
            private CustomStack<T> stack;

            public MyEnumerator(CustomStack<T> stack)
            {
                this.stack = stack;
                position = -1;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {

            }
            public void Reset()
            {
                position = -1;
            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                position++;
                return position < stack.Count;
            }

            Object IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get
                {
                    return stack.arr[position];
                }
            }
            public T Current
            {
                get
                {
                    return stack.arr[position];

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you spent any effort debugging? Just step through and see what happens.

Comment: This question was closed as "too localized"; I disagree with this assessment. I have seen multiple people make this mistake. (Both the general mistake of modifying an iterated collection, and the specific mistake of popping a stack while iterating it and only getting half the elements out as a result.)

Answer (score 15):

You are doing something that you are required to *never do*: you are *modifying* a collection *while you are iterating it with an enumerator*.  (The `foreach` loop is a syntactic sugar for allocating an enumerator.)

The documentation for `IEnumerable` actually suggests that an implementation like yours *throw an exception* if your data structure is modified while being enumerated. (Try it with `List<T>` and you'll see; the list will throw if you add or remove an item while the list is being enumerated in `foreach`.)

That's the cause of your problem; your data structure is not designed to either (1) throw when abused, or (2) behave well when abused, and therefore it's behaving badly when you abuse it.

My advice: if it hurts when you do that, don't do that. Don't modify a collection while in a loop that is enumerating it.

Instead, make an `IsEmpty` property and write your loop:

```
while(!collection.IsEmpty)  
  Console.WriteLine(collection.Pop());
```

That way you are not modifying the collection *while there is an enumerator being processed at the same time*.

The specific problem you've got here is: `position` is always increasing every time through the loop. And `count` is always decreasing.  You say that only half the items are getting counted. Well, work it out. If you have ten items, position starts at zero, and increases until it is greater than count, then every time through the loop...

```
position    count
 0           10
 1           9
 2           8
 3           7
 4           6
 5           5
```

and we're done, and we've only enumerated half the items.

If you want to make your collection robust in the face of being modified while being iterated then *`position` has to change when the stack is pushed or popped*. It can't just blindly increase each time even though the count is changing. Working out the correct behavior is quite tricky, which is why the documentation recommends that you simply throw.

If you want to make your collection throw an exception when modified while being enumerated, the trick is to make the object have an int called the "version number". Every time you push or pop the collection, change the version number. Then have the iterator take a copy of the version number when the iteration starts; if it ever detects that the current version number differs from the copy, then the collection has been modified during the enumeration and you can throw a collection modified exception.

Thanks for the interesting question; I shall likely use it as both an example in my blog, and possibly see if I can write a static analyzer that detects this kind of dangerous modification.

Comment: Also note that you could follow the pattern of `BlockingCollection` and have a `GetConsumingEnumerable`.  The key difference there is that you aren't modifying the collection in the body of the `foreach` that is enumerating it, you're getting an enumerable that *from the definition of the enumerator* is modifying the underlying collection.  Such an enumerator can even be written externally: `static IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable<T>(this CustomStack<T> s){while(!s.IsEmpty)yield return s.Pop();}`

Comment: What would be the pros and cons of having a one-time-enumerable type implement a method named `GetEnumerator`, so as to allow `foreach`, without implementing `IEnumerable<T>`?  Being able to `foreach` something that can only be enumerated once is certainly handy, but `IEnumerable<T>` is generally expected to allow repeated enumeration.

Comment: You don't have to check for increases, but you can also make a copy of data. I am using this while creating enumerator.